Find all the positive solutions of a Diophantine equation in three variables
When trying to solve a problem in numerical semigroups, I found that the problem amounts to solving a Diophantine equation that depends on one parameter (namely $n$), in the positive integers. Since my experience with Diophantine equations is limited to linear equations with constant coefficients, I am not sure about how to approach this problem. The additional restriction that the solutions should be positive adds an extra degree of difficulty. The equation in question is
$$ x n + z (n+2) = y(n+1), $$
where $n > 1$. I want to find all the integer solutions with $x, y, z > 0$. I think we can easily find a subset of the solutions by splitting all the terms into two categories: those having $n$ and those not having $n$, as follows:
$$xn + zn = yn, \quad 2z = y.$$
Thus we have two linear Diophantine equations
$$x + z = y, \quad 2z = y,$$
which have an obvious solution, namely $x=z$ (where $x,z > 0$) and $y=2x=2z$. However, I am afraid that I might be overlooking some solutions. Is there any general methodology for approaching this kind of problem, or just ad hoc solutions?

This is linear....you can rewrite it as $n(x+y-z)=y-2z$.  So just choose $(y,z)$ so that $y-2z$ is divisible by $n$ and compute $x$ accordingly.
